# How to create react components which share functions but have independent state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create two React component. They need to share common functions. These functions uses `this.setState()`, so I could not put them inside a helper file. I tried using `composition`. This enable me to share functions but they also share state.

I need something like

```
//file 1
var Component1 = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            //return some common + new states
        }
});

//file 2
var Component2 = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            //return some common + new states
        }
});

// file 3
// This file needs to have some functions, which can do:
this.setState(); //on state of Component1 and Component2.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple options here.

## A store

If these components are completely independent, you can use a store to keep and update the data that each component uses, and subscribe to the store. This is the Flux/Redux pattern.

A component might look like this

```
class Component1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(...props) {
    super(...props)
    this.update = this.update.bind(this)
    this.state = { count: 0 }
  }

  update (storeData) {
    this.setState(storeData)
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    store.subscribe(this.update)
  }

  componentDidUnmount () {
    store.unsubscribe(this.update)
  }

  render () {
    return (<span>You have clicked {this.state.count} times</span>)
  }
}
```

The thing to note here is that the store doesn't have direct access to the component's state. The component subscribes, and some other mechanism will publish data. The store will call the registered callback will this happens. A ***very*** simple store might look like this

```
const store = {
  subscriptions: new Set(),
  data: {},
  subscribe: function (callback) {
    this.subscriptions.add(callback)
  },
  unsubscribe: function (callback) {
    this.subscriptions.delete(callback)
  },
  update: function (key, value) {
    this.data[key] = value
    this.subscriptions.forEach(cb => cb(this.data))
  }
}
```

This allows anyone with access to the store to update any/all components that are subscribed to it.

```
const CounterButton = () => (
  <button onClick={() => store.update('count', (store.data.count || 0) + 1)}>Increase Count</button>
)
```

Here is a very [contrived codepen](http://codepen.io/tyrsius/pen/gwYXxV?editors=0010#0) demonstrating this

## Parent Component

If your components are both children of a shared component, then their parent can update them by updating their `props`, instead of updating their state. It can keep track of this using its own, internal state.

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(...props) {
    super(...props)
    this.state = { clicks: 0 }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ clicks: this.state.clicks + 1})}>Increase Count</button>
        <Component1 clicks={this.state.clicks} />
        <Component2 clicks={this.state.clicks} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
const Component1 = ({clicks}) => (
  <span>You have clicked {clicks} times</span>
)

const Component2 = (props) => (
  <span>You have pressed {props.clicks} times</span>
)
```

Here is an [equally contrived codepen](http://codepen.io/tyrsius/pen/xEKPYJ?editors=0010#0) demonstrating this

## Something <s>insane</s> else

The above two are the recommended way to go. But this is JavaScript, and we have less rules than the Wild West. If you really want to directly control the state of components from some shared function, there is **nothing stopping you**.

```
var sharedComponents = new Set()

function incrementComponents () {
  sharedComponents.forEach(c => c.setState({clicks: c.state.clicks + 1}))
}

class Component1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(...props) {
    super(...props)
    this.state = { clicks: 0 }
    sharedComponents.add(this)
  }

  render () {
    return (<span>You have clicked {this.state.clicks} times</span>)
  }
}

setInterval(incrementComponents, 1000)
```

Here is a [completely insane codepen](http://codepen.io/tyrsius/pen/RGbjyz?editors=0010#0) demonstrating this.

Comment: Your solution with redux will work but I am not using redux in my application.

The second solution does not work in this case as I am trying to use component1 and component2 at completely different places. 

I am using `mixins` currently to solve the issue. I know it is deprecated, but I could not create the same using Higher Order Components.

Comment: My first solution does not require redux, redux is simply a mature implementation of the pattern. I provided a fully functioning micro-store that you could copy/paste and use in your app.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the both `Component1` & `Component2` under a `Parent component`, and if you pass the parent component function to the child component then both `Component1` & `Component2` will have the `Parent Component` functions as a `props`. so you get your `common` function like this way as react component works in a `parent-child relationship`. children's can get the data from their parent. and this way all your child component have their own state too.

Comment: Right, but this parent function has to be able to change child state, which is not the case I think. 
I am using something like this, because there are lot of common functions related to state.